# Xcode in Swift: navigation bar not showing in UI collection view (simulator)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I am in an effort of creating an app project that uses collection view to present a list of screenshots. In the storyboard, I am pretty certain that I have the navigation bar (Root View of a Navigation Controller) set up (see the first image attached) with the constraints shown in the second image.

However, when I run the app in simulator, the navigation bar seems hidden (or covered up by the collection view??). I was wondering if I should shrink the height of the collection view in order to make the navigation bar visible.

[image: collection view in the root view controller]

[image: constraints for the collection view]

[image: navigation bar not showing up in simulator]

Comment: Can you add a auto-layout constraint that sets the top margin to 0 from the navigation bar? I usually would use a UIContainderView and put my UICollectionViewController embedded in it.

Comment: thanks Oscar! Will try that when I get home!

Answer (score 1):

If you say, you've set everything correctly, try this. It might work.

In your

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```